# Python DataFrame : Remove rows based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df with two columns `name` and `score`. I'm trying to keep only the rows for each user where score > 1 starts.

```
    df

            name       score     
    0       bruno        0         
    1       bruno        0         
    2       bruno        15        
    3       bruno        0        
    4       paul         0         
    5       paul         0          
    6       paul         25
    7       paul         0
    8       paul         10
    9       marcus        5
    10      mason         0
```

final df

```
            name       score            
    2       bruno        15        
    3       bruno        0                 
    6       paul         25
    7       paul         0
    8       paul         10
    9       marcus        5
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
x = df[df.groupby("name")["score"].cumsum().gt(0)]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
     name  score
2   bruno     15
3   bruno      0
6    paul     25
7    paul      0
8    paul     10
9  marcus      5
```

Comment: Very lean solution. I guess a little explanation would be great. Cheers!

Comment: Question, what happens if the first entry for a name is 0? isnt that entry erased?

Comment: @FloLie It's doing `cumsum()` in groups. so if first entry in the group is 0, the entry is erased (until first non-zero one).

Comment: Is that the desired outcome? I assumed all entries are of interest for these groups

Comment: @FloLie I think yes, based on *"I'm trying to keep only the rows for each user where score > 1 starts"*

Comment: I should have read more closely. You are right